# Editing DNS IP on Current network

Tags: networking, dns

I have on our network a Linux intranet box that we had to move to another location, this is on a server 2008 Domain Controlled net. My predecessor left me 0 information on the network.. I have done an nslookup to find the existing hostname address on the DNS server BUT I cannot find out where I would edit this on the DNS server to change that to an updated IP address on a new subnet.. Can anyone please help...

TY

Answer (score 0):

Via the Windows DNS configuration utility, which, assuming a standard 2008 AD domain, would be on the Windows Domain Controller (at least) under "Administrative Tools".

The icon for the DNS configuration utility will look something like this:

[image]

You'll be looking to add it to your Forward Lookup Zone, and perhaps the Reverse as well.

More info from MS: [Administering DNS Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794771(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Yes I know where the DNS config is but the question is when it's not showing up in the DNS Config would it be listed elsewhere??